# Changes made to object attribute not seen when using the multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

When using multiprocessing in Python, and you're importing a module, why is is that any instance variables in the module are pass by copy to the child process, whereas and arguments passed in the `args()` parameter are pass by reference.

Does this have to do with thread safety perhaps?

**foo.py**

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


foo_user = User('foo')
```

**main.py**

```
import multiprocessing

from foo import User, foo_user

def worker(main_foo):
    print(main_foo.name) #prints 'main user'
    print(foo_user.name) #prints 'foo user', why doesn't it print 'override'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main_foo = User('main user')
    foo_user.name = 'override'

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(main_foo,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

EDIT: I'm an idiot, `self.name = None` should have been `self.name = name`. I made the correction in my code and forgot to copy it back over.

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it *does* print override. Look at this:

```
$ python main.py
None
override
```

But! This only happens on *Nix. My guess is that you are running on Windows. The difference being that, in Windows, a fresh copy of the interpreter is spawned to just run your function, and the change you made to `foo_user.name` is not made, because in this new instance, `__name__` is not `__main__`, so that bit of code is not executed. This is done to prevent infinite recursion.

You'll see the difference if you add this line to your function:

```
def worker(main_foo):
    print(__name__)
    ...
```

This prints `__main__` on *Nix. However, it will not be `__main__` for Windows.

You'll want to *move* that line out of the `if __name__ == __main__` block, if you want it to work.